# Multipart Form is not parsed in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new in CakePHP

I have a form with code like this

```
$this->Form->create($ModelName, array("type"=>"file",'url' => array("controller"=>$ControllerName,"action"=>"CommitEdit", $ID,$page,$viewpage),'class' => 'form','novalidate'));
```

but when i submit the post, the controller doesnt have

```
$this->request->data //yield empty array
```

but it did have

```
$this->request->input() //multipart form body
```

also the action in controller resulting 403 Forbiden, even without any code inside the action

**Edited**

I tried to check, apparently, $_POST is also empty

Comment: its cakephp 2.x or cakephp 3.x?

Comment: cakephp 3.x, i already found the problem and the solutions, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try this simple method its work for you .

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('$ModelName',array("type"=>"POST","action"=>"CommitEdit",'class' => 'form' ,'novalidate')); 
echo $this->Form->input('$ModelName.ID',array("type"=>"text","placeholder" => "ID")); 
echo $this->Form->input('$ModelName.page',array("type"=>"file","placeholder" => "page")); 
echo $this->Form->input('$ModelName.viewpage',array("type"=>"text","placeholder" => "viewpage")); 
echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, i already found the problem and the solutions, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around, i found the problem that when i use Form Helper with type "file", it create hidden field "_method" and then the value is "PUT", this make PHP can;t parse the multipart data, so i had to use normal  tag,

or use type "POST" and put "enc-type=multipart/formdata" property manually